# Преобразование итератора в указатель

Tags: c++

Мне нужно в деке указателей найти указатель на элемент, переданный в функцию, и из одного дека этот указатель переместить в другой.

```
    void Deallocate(T* object) {
    deque<T*>::iterator a = find(allotted.begin(), allotted.end(), object);
    if (a != allotted.end()) {
        T* param = *a;
        exempted.push_back(param);
        allotted.erase(a);
    }
    }
```

Деки:

```
deque<T*> allotted, exempted;
```

Т.к присваивание, которое написано выше, компилятор не принимает, может кто объяснить, в чем проблема и как мне преобразовать итератор в указатель? Или лучше вообще через for ranged делать?

Comment: Приведите ошибку дословно.

Comment: Ошибка C2760 синтаксическая ошибка: ожидался токен "<Нет данных>", а не "<Нет данных>".

И 
Ошибка C7510 "iterator": при использовании зависимого имени тип необходимо указать префикс "имя типа"

Comment: `typename deque<T*>::iterator a = ...`

Comment: Или лучше вообще `auto a = find(...);`.

Comment: Ага, и правда забыл про typename. А auto я пытался использовать, но он там тоже ошибку дает.

Comment: Хотя что-то странно, попробовал сейчас с авто и все заработало. Но во всяком случае спасибо.

Comment: @Croessmah, с помощью вашего ответа я исправил ошибку, но не понимаю,зачем тут нужен typename(или class)

Comment: @Elvin http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2006/08/typename.html